# Gradle - create custom task with command line parameters

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm looking for a way to pass a parameter to a custom Gradle task. (Gradle 5.1.1)

I have created a task:

```
public class MyTask extends DefaultTask {

private String url;

  @Optional
  public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
  }

  @Input
  public String getUrl() {
    return url;
  }

  @TaskAction
  public void run() {
    System.out.println("URL IS " + getUrl());
 }
}
```

This is similar to the example given at:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#example_declaring_a_command_line_option

On the next step i created a plugin which hosts this task.

```
public class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project>, TasksProducingPlugin {

  @Override
  public void apply(Project project) {
    MyTask myTask = project.getTasks().create("exampleTask", MyTask.class);
    myTask.setDescription("...");
    myTask.setGroup(TASK_GROUP_NAME);
    myTask.run();

  @Override
  public Collection<String> taskNames() {
    Collection<String> collection = new HashSet<>();
    collection.add("exampleTask");
    return collection;
  }
}
```

Now i want to run the exampleTask from the command line and provide the value for the url.

I try:

```
gradlew exampleTask --url=http://www.google.com/
```

And get:

```
Unknown command-line option '--url'.
```

Also tried:

```
gradlew exampleTask -Purl=http://www.google.com/
```

And get:

```
No value has been specified for property 'url'.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation again. You have annotated your setter method with `@Optional` instead of `@Option`.